# Access VBA/SQL "Run-Time error '424': Object required"

Tags: sql, vba

I keep on getting getting a "Run-Time error '424': Object required" and I am not sure why, when I press debug it takes me to the line `qdf.SQL = strSQL` and highlights it yellow. I was wondering if anybody knows what is the problem?

```
Sub UpdateX()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("References")

strSQL = "SELECT References.DocNum, References.Availability " & _
     "FROM References " & _
     "WHERE References.Source = 'Book' " & _
     "ORDER BY References.DocNum;"
qdf.SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryTest"
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, technical question of this type belong on Stack Overflow. Admins will migrate it there, so please do not double post.

Comment: where have you declared/initialized object `qdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qdf` is `Nothong` (null).  You need to set `qdf` to something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`strSQL = "SELECT References.DocNum, References.Availability FROM References WHERE References.Source = 'Book' ORDER BY References.DocNum;"`
`Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)`
`Do until rs.EOF`
    'str2 = Update query based upon rs
    `DoCmd.RunSQL STR2`
`rs.MoveNext`
`Loop`
`rs.Close`